# How to check if user input contains one word from a list of possible words

Tags: python, iterable

I'm making a text adventure and I want to check if the user inputs something that contains one key word out of a list of possible words, and if contains more it will error message.  `any` checks if there are any elements that are true and `all` checks if all of them are true.  How would I go about checking if only one returns true?  Is there an if statement I could add to the `any`?